# XPath to set multiple values

Tags: xml, xpath, biztalk, biztalk-2013

In the message below, I want to set the 2 'invunique' nodes to a parameter vParam.
I can easily set 'cvalue' using

```
xpath(MyMsg.Body, "//*[local-name()='cvalue']") = vParam;
```

But I've not found a nice way of setting the 2 'invunique' nodes in 1 XPath statement, any ideas?

```
<ns0:newcase xmlns:ns0="http://MyNamespace/v1-0">
<ns0:caseheader>
  <ns0:caseunique>10</ns0:caseunique> 
</ns0:caseheader>
<ns0:financials>
 <ns0:invoices>
   <ns0:invoice>
       <ns0:caseunique>10</ns0:caseunique> 
       <ns0:invunique>10</ns0:invunique> 
       <ns0:invudfs>
         <ns0:invudf>
           <ns0:invunique>20</ns0:invunique> 
           <ns0:cvalue>cvalue_0</ns0:cvalue> 
           <ns0:otherdesc>otherdesc_0</ns0:otherdesc> 
         </ns0:invudf>
       </ns0:invudfs>
  </ns0:invoice>
 </ns0:invoices>
</ns0:financials>
</ns0:newcase>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know (I haven't tested this unfortunately), the xpath function 'setter' will only be able to update the first match. If you would have a second cvalue node, only the first one would have been updated.

Any reason why you would want both updated in one statement instead of having 2 statements?

If this is a recurring node, I would suggest to involve a mapping or helper class instead.

Comment: 2 statements would do it I suppose.  I'm using a c# utility to set the variables then want to use the variables to update the message without the need of a map. Can I ask what the structure of the xpath would be to set the 2nd invunique value then?